# Series involving Euler totient function $\varphi(n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, totient-function

Prove that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n\varphi(n)}{1-x^n}=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$

where $\varphi$ is the Euler totient function.

I can see in [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+n%3D1+to+infinity+of+x%5En+EulerPhi%5Bn%5D%2F(1-x%5En)) that this is the case, but how to prove it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Expanding out $\frac{1}{1-x^n}$ in a power series leads to
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n\phi(n)}{1-x^n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\phi(n)x^n\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^{nk}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\phi(n)\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^{nk} $$
For a given $m\geq 1$, the coefficient of $x^m$ in the above sum is $\sum_{d|m}\phi(d)=m$, hence
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n\phi(n)}{1-x^n}=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}mx^m$$

Finally, differentiating the geometric series
$$ \frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}x^m$$
and multiplying by $x$ shows that 
$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}mx^m=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$